# xamarin ios Tableview is not getting Reloaded when i use MvxSimpleTableViewSource

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

My table view does not update whenever its source property is changed. The code is as follows:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        viewmodel = this.ViewModel as ListViewModel;
        viewmodel.PropertyChanged += HandlePropertyChangedEventHandler;;
        var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource( TableView, LaborCell.Key, LaborCell.Key);
        TableView.Source = source;
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ListView, ListViewModel>();
        set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.LaborTransactions);
        set.Apply();
        TableView.ReloadData();
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
        public class ListViewModel :MaxRawBaseViewModel
            {

          public ListViewModel():base()
                {
                    LoadLaborTransactions();
                }

         private Collection<LaborTransaction> _laborTransactions;

                public Collection<LaborTransaction> LaborTransactions
                {
                    get { return _laborTransactions; }     
                }

     public void LoadLaborTransactions()
            {
                _laborTransactions = DataService.GetLaborTransactions(somenumber);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => LaborTransactions); 

            }

}
```

When ever the change in `Transactions`  am calling the `tablview.reolad()` on propertychanged method. but it is not reloading my tableview

```
void HandlePropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e){
            if (e.PropertyName.Equals("LaborTransactions"))
            {
                       TableView.ReloadData();
            }
    }
```

Comment: You use `.To(vm => vm.transactions);` which should be `.To(vm => vm.Transactions);` which I think is a typo? Not sure if this is the problem because I think this won't even compile. Could you share the full view and the code where you update the `Transactions` property?

Comment: @JKL thanks. That is just a typo error.

Comment: No. .To(vm => vm.Transactions); this is what i have in my code.

Comment: Alright, could you then provide the rest of your view and viewmodel code?

Comment: I have edited the code @JKL

Answer (score 1):

`Collection<T>` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You can verify that in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1?view=netcore-2.2). You need to change your `LaborTransactions` property to a collection type that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` like `ObservableCollection<T>` and `MvxObservableCollection<T>`. You can see that `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netcore-2.2)

Change your `LaborTransactions` as such:

```
private ObservableCollection<LaborTransaction> _laborTransactions;
public ObservableCollection<LaborTransaction> LaborTransactions
{
    get { return _laborTransactions; }
    set {
        return _laborTransactions;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => LaborTransactions);
    }
}
```